# ES6 - How to import subsets of a module while keeping the module.submodule notation?

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

I started using ES6 style imports with Webpack, and I have code which looks like this:

```
import { find } from 'lodash';

find(someArray, 5);
```

I'd like to keep the same import notation to only load the subset of lodash that I use, but I find it difficult to understand the code, especially when you have multiple imports from different libraries.

Is there any way to be able to write:

```
lodash.find(someArray, 5);
```

while only importing what I need from lodash?

Comment: Why not `import` and rename like `import { find as lodash_find } from 'lodash';`?

Comment: ES really needs a `import {find} as lodash from 'lodash';` notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't because `import lodash from 'lodash'` load all the library. But you can load partially the library and reassign the function to an object :

```
import { find } from 'lodash';
const lodash = { find };
lodash.find(someArray, 5);
```

Comment: I was hoping to find something built-in, but this will have to do. Thanks!